# Bootstrap 3 buttons rendering with bad CSS and misaligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71j5psr0/) (you'll have to expand the **Result** pane to see it in all its glory).

Notice how the green **Sign up** button is:

- Pinned to the top of the navbar; and
- Doesn't seem to look like a normal "success" button ([example here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-single))

I can't tell if it's because I'm using a CDN (and perhaps the CDN is out of date) or if these 2 things are happening because I'm lacking some CSS rules in the following code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><button type="button" class="button btn-success">Sign up</button></li>
    <li class="active"><button type="button" class="button btn-link">Sign in</button></li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Comment: If your <ul> a child of a <div class="container">?

Comment: Thanks @TheGeekYouNeed (+1) - what makes you think it isn't already? Did you look at the jsFiddle for the full context?

Comment: Looking now.  I didn't look at the Fiddle, - I scrolled too far down and missed the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to use the **btn** class instead of **button** class on your buttons, then you need to wrap your buttons inside a navbar form parent to position them properly like so:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Sign up</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Sign in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/71j5psr0/6/

You should probably change your buttons to links, just keep in mind in a navbar by default links inside of your list items will take up the full height of the navbar itself and will be inherit a unique style. You can apply the same btn-* classes to links and they will appear exactly as buttons do.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this `class="btn btn-success btn-lg"`
In your code YOU use "button" in the place of "btn"